# Android, does URL stores in history when using in app WebView?

Tags: android, webview, browser-history

I have a question regard history of default browser in Android.
I want to know if an application uses WebView to display a URL, does this url is accessable when another application gets history of default browser?
example: Application A contains a webview that loads `www.A_SITE.com/terms.html`.
Application B has a feature that get history of default( or Chrome) browser by `cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);` and pass it to its back-end server.

So my question is does this address `www.A_SITE.com/terms.html` will be retrieved by above query? I read [WebView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and although It mentioned that it doesn't include any features of web browser, I didn't find they mention that its history is private and is not accessible by queries.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Based on my experience, each `WebView` stores it's own history. However, any URL opened in a `WebView` is not accessible by browser's history.

I don't know the real reason, but my guess is related to how App in Android runs in a sandboxed process (app data is not accessible by other app)